# Corpus vs Vocabulary vs Document in NLP

Tags: nlp, nltk

In a very simple and understandable term, because I read a lot of blogs which further more confused me,

1. [read but couldnt understand](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/472640/in-nlp-what-is-the-difference-between-corpus-and-vocabulary-or-are-they-the-sa#:%7E:text=Corpus%3A%20Collection%20of%20texts%20used,to%20train%20an%20NLP%20model.)
2. [read but couldnt understand](https://www.quora.com/In-NLP-what-is-the-difference-between-a-Lexicon-and-a-Corpus)

Suppose I have five rows in my DataFrame

```
1. This is Foo, how can I help you
2. It might rain today
3. I love football
4. Crazy, Stupid & Love
5. I shot the sheriff
```

In this, Can anyone help me to understand which one should be called as a Document, Vocabulary and Corpus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In NLP, **document** concept can be a bit vague: a document is a unit, so it can correspond to different text objects, such as entire documents, sentences, passages...
In your example, `"This is Foo, how can I help you"` is a document. `"It might rain today"` is another document...

A **corpus** is a collection of documents.
In your example, the corpus is composed by 5 documents.

The **vocabulary** is the list of all the words contained in the corpus, therefore all the words contained in all the documents.
Your vocabulary is
`[&, can, crazy, foo, football, help, how, i, is, it, love, might, rain, sheriff, shot, stupid, the, this, today, you]`